# What is the best way to 'loosely' compare strings in C# without discerning between various types of spaces?

Tags: c#, string

I need to contact an external piece of software that only replies in text. I need to interpret this text as a key. For example, when receiving the text `foo bar`, I need to be able to do the following:

```
var expectedResult = "foo bar";
if (actualResult == expectedResult) {
 // do something
}
```

My challenge is that the external software uses different characters than I would expect. When I log it, it says `"foo bar"`, but the if statement is false. Upon further inspection of the actual characters, this is because the actual result uses a unicode character `space` `0x0020`, whereas the string that I enter in C# uses a `no-break space`  `0x00A0`.

I have tried some things, such as calling `.Replace(@"\x0020", " ")`, `.Normalize()` and `.Equals` on both string, but nothing seems to change the character content or evaluate to `true`.

What would be a good way to tackle this? Especially keeping in mind that I need to check for more than one key, so my ideal option is to compare loosely (e.g. no distinction between `space` and `no-break space`, and also no distinction between other highly similar

Comment: This isn't a typo. It was caused by copy-and-paste. It's a valid question that deserves an answer other than "type over the bad character".

Answer (score 2):

So I was about to post this question - then solved it indirectly by finding out that it's a non-issue - and figured I'd still post my findings to potentially help someone else. This was my own fault. I copied the compare string `var expectedResult = "foo bar";` from the command line output of my local Docker set-up, and that contained the character caused the issues by having the space as a `no-break space`. By simply pressing backspace on that character and typing space, I fixed it.